# Can I use percentage for the entire width of my site?

Tags: html, css, width

There are many types of display that people use, so it is hard to expect what resolutions will your user use to view your site. To avoid this problem, I am thinking using percentage instead of pixels, em and pt to define the web layout. However, is this a good practice to do this? Including using the percentage, eg 80% for the main wrapper ?

I know it is hard to do it when it come to determine the width of the inner element. I'll have to calculate the percentages based on the each div's parent. How do you guys cope with this problem when it come to different browser's resolution?

Comment: IMO, it's better practice than using constant sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Css media query is best solution for this check this http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

There's obviously debate between fluid and fixed layouts, but fluid layouts can work very well as well.

An example is [smashing magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/) (try resizing your window with the site loaded).

I believe that it would be a lot easier if you use a framework of some sort. If you have used any grids CSS framework before, you can have a look at [Liquid Blueprint](https://github.com/Montoya/blueprint-plugin---liquidgrid). This allows you to work in a grid based manner, but have the page fluidly resize according to the browser's size.

Answer (score 0):

I use percentages for every width within the outer container but have min-width: and max-width: for the container itself, so it scales a small amount. Say 960px for min width and 1160px for the max width. This way it works larger screen sizes better and if I want to I can go back and make it responsive because its already all in percentages.